no rule to process (folder/path...) of type 'text.xml' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
Anyone has ever get this error? i haven't open my mac for a days and this suddenly happened, i tried modifying the podfile by adding this script from chatgpt and no result, i also tried any solution on Github issue, i cannot upgrade the firebase version since it will take a lot of effort to upgrade the flutter version. let me know if im missing something here.
# Remove PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy from FirebaseMessaging target
if target.name == 'FirebaseMessaging'
  target.resources_build_phase.files.each do |file|
    if file.display_name == 'PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy'
      file.remove_from_project
    end
  end



did you tried with pod install?

flutter clean flutter pub get cd ios pod install after running this run the command pod install

i've tried it, no result

try this command pod install --repo-update

Did this worked ?
